# Creating bottom main view bar in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I want to create a regular main view bar like most Ios apps have for navigation between the main views.

The problem is for the newer devices that uses gestures instead of the traditional home button have a very large safe area above the bottom of the device.

I can do the following using `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)`:

```
var body: some View {
      
            VStack(spacing:0){


              MainView()//Containing if blocks to determine the current selected view from the bar
             
              Spacer()


              BottomBar()


      }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)


}
```

The problem is that a lot of views are "escaping" from the top of the screen, so it solves a problem regarding the bar but creates a bigger problem for the other view.

What is the correct way to implement a bottomBar that is really close to the bottom of the screen like most apps implement ?

Comment: Are you looking for a TabView? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tabview